# Сменить цвет кнопок js

Tags: javascript, html

Есть массив с данными, там есть кнопки, мне нужно чтобы при нажатие на конкретную кнопку менялся цвет только этой кнопки.

```
 <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>

 <button type="button" style="width: 90px; height: 90px" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick="StatusProduct(this)" >
 <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" style="font-size: 50px"></i>
 <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']?>
 </button>
<?php } ?>
```

я нашел пример как поминать цвет одной кнопки

```
 <input onclick="change(this)" type="submit" value="Перевести" title="Перевести">
 var color = 'green'; 
function change(identifier) {
    identifier.style.background = color;
}
```

А как это сделать в массиве ?

Comment: Чтобы в цикле не добавлять каждой кнопке обработчик, можно же поймать событие на них свыше. Делегируйте обработчик их общему родителю и проверяйте target на наличие  класса. Пример приведу ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('click',e=>{  
  if (e.target.classList.contains('btn')) {
    [...e.target.parentElement.children].map(el=>el.style.background="");
    e.target.style.background="red";
  } 
})
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="btn">one</button>
  <button class="btn">two</button>
  <button class="btn">three</button>
  <button class="btn">four</button>
  <button class="btn">five</button>
</div>
```